# Some Flash applications do not work on Ubuntu (9.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, flash, compatibility, youtube

Some Flash sites do not work well on my computer (Ubuntu 9.10).

Example: youtube.com - can't hear sounds.

http://animesquish.org/anime/queens-blade-heir-to-the-throne-episode-01/ - I see only the first second of each movie and then it freezes.

What am I missing?

Here is the output of `dpkg -l | grep flash`:

```
ii  flashplugin-installer                10.0.42.34ubuntu0.9.10.1                   Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
ii  flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound       0.0.svn2431-3                              Adobe Flash Player platform support library
```

Comment: what flash package(s) did you install?  run `dpkg -l | grep flash` and add this info to your post, please.

Comment: Video driver? Also: sudo apt-get install libflashsupport

Comment: What is the correct source to take it from?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting desperate you can try to download the latest Flash plugin from Adobe itself and installing it in `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/`.